# Excel with macro not working in office 365 on Mac with OS X

Tags: excel, vba, macos, office365

I have a client who wants to use an Excel sheet with Macros on his Macbook Pro with OS X and Office 365 for Mac.

When he opens the file, the buttons and dropdowns are converted to images.

Any suggestions?

Also, it can not do even simple macro operations like clearing a cell.

I get error 438 when trying to run a code that clears a cell. Figure 2 shows the list of references, and there are not many to pick from. Can I install some references to make it work, and how? Or is this a dead end?

Making a `msgbox "hello"` in the macro works fine, if i just play it.

Thanks, Emil

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using ActiveX controls, which are not supported on Macs. You'll have to switch to Form controls, unless your client wants to use a VM and run a Windows version of Excel.

Comment: @Rory Okay, thanks, that might be it. I just dont understand why it wont even do a simple cells(1,1).Clear command (set to run on startup). Isnt the ActiveX only needed on the buttons?

Comment: If you have references to activex controls in the same routine it may be causing the compiler issues since they effectively don't exist.

Comment: I dont think i do. It is just an auto_open rutine (Runs on startup), and it just clears some cell values. At least thats where it complains.

Comment: It looks from your picture as though you do (eg your `Sheets("..").combobox1.additem`), but they are late bound calls so I'm not sure that's the issue. Comment them all out and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: @Rory You might be right. I updated with one more screenshot. It is clearing of the ActiveX combobox. So what is use are comboboxes/drop downs and a few buttons. Then some operationsin VBA, simple algebra. Do you think i can tweak this to work on a Mac?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks, good point. However, it is installed - It is not an online version.

Comment: @EmilOlsen - Yeah, sorry, I reviewed quesiton and realized my mistake from pictures.

Comment: If you can replace the activex controls with the built-in Form versions, then the code should work on a Mac from the little of it I can see. Activex controls are best avoided anyway as they are problematic.